# confirming if the query i wrote is right for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT  * FROM table1 WHERE 
DateTimeCreated > now() - interval 30 minute and (cust is not null and (CustomerID != 0))

UNION 

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
DateTimeStamp > now() - interval 30 minute and (cust is not null and (CustomerID != 0)) 

limit 1000
```

will it get the right records or there is anotehr way of doing the same thing

please guide

Thanks

Comment: How do we know from what you've given us?  You need to provide sample data, and expected results.  Also, why can't you tell whether this query is giving you the correct results?

Comment: it seems correct to me but it is really another way of doing it instead of doing a union

Comment: Doing what?  You haven't told us your objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single query with `OR`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (DateTimeCreated > now() - interval 30 minute OR DateTimeStamp > now() - interval 30 minute)
    AND cust is not null and CustomerID != 0
```

However, if `DateTimeCreated` and `DateTimeStamp` are indexed, your query will probably run faster. MySQL is not good at using indexes in `OR` conditions.

Comment: its throwing an error 
```1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
      AND cust is not null and CustomerID != 0' at line 3```

Comment: typo, I left out the second `minute`